# Callback URL is ignoring parameter value after &

Tags: asp.net, url, vbscript, asp-classic, referrals

I got stuck at this point. After login i am getting referral-url which i am putting into **www.url.com?par1=val&callback="referral-url"**. My referral url is like **www.ref-url.com?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3**. My problem is that i am getting a cut url i.e., **www.ref-url.com?param1=val1**  after login. I think it is ignoring url after '**&**'.I am using classic asp for development. Any Help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Server.URLEncode` if you're including a URL as a querystring parameter, especially if the included URL also contains querystrings.

```
Dim login_redirect, login_referrer

login_redirect = "http://www.url.com/?par1=val&callback="
login_referrer = "http://www.ref-url.com/?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3"

response.write login_redirect & Server.URLEncode(login_referrer)
```

Output:

```
http://www.url.com/?par1=val&callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eref%2Durl%2Ecom%2F%3Fparam1%3Dval1%26param2%3Dval2%26param3%3Dval3
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply. Now It is redirecting to http://www.url.com after login. Any guesses

Answer (score 0):

Passing the URL with query inside another URL query is a bit tricky. The only way it works is to encode it. For example:

```
https://website.com/?a=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2F%3Fz%3D1%26y%3D2
```

But, when you want to return to the url you passed through query, you need to decode it otherwise it will not work. You can use the following function on your "login Page" before redirecting the url.

```
Function URLDecode(sConvert)
Dim aSplit
Dim sOutput
Dim I

If IsNull(sConvert) Then
    URLDecode = ""
    Exit Function
End If

' convert all pluses to spaces
sOutput = REPLACE(sConvert, "+", " ")

' next convert %hexdigits to the character
aSplit = Split(sOutput, "%")

If IsArray(aSplit) Then
    sOutput = aSplit(0)
    For I = 0 to UBound(aSplit) - 1
        sOutput = sOutput & _
        Chr("&H" & Left(aSplit(i + 1), 2)) &_
        Right(aSplit(i + 1), Len(aSplit(i + 1)) - 2)
    Next
End If

URLDecode = sOutput
End Function
```

For example, you should have above function and the following code on your login page:

```
Dim callback
callback = Request("callback")
callback = URLDecode(callback)
Response.redirect(callback)
```

Comment: `request.querystring` will automatically decode the URL, so a decode function isn't necessary in this case.